# Are there dialects of YAML or just differences in parsing it?

Tags: cloud, yaml, aws-cloudformation

We use YAML in several frameworks to define types and structures for our deployments. I read an [article](https://github.com/cblp/yaml-sucks) about why some people don't like YAML and they stated that the parsing of YAML is very different depending on the interpreter.

Can it be said that these interpreters define their own dialects of YAML or would that not be the case?

The background is that we would like to verify and validate YAML in our templates.

Comment: Please add the link of the article.

Comment: @030 Done...Please read it.

Comment: What should be the programming language of the yaml validator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is only one [YAML spec](http://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html). That would lead me to say "There are no YAML dialects". There are certainly differences in **implementation**, perhaps due to what the article claims as the spec's ambiguity:

> YAML specification is so ambiguous,

It's a matter of opinion, I believe, but there is no doubting that various language-specific parsers of the same data result in different output. So, to answer the question(s):

1. **no** there are no YAML dialects (since there is one spec)
2. **yes** the spec provides much leeway for implementation and thus there are differences in how it is parsed.